# How to integrate xero api in codeigniter public type

Tags: php, json, xml, codeigniter

I want to integrate xero to my codeigniter(PHP) site. Could you please anyone help me. Is there any library for public type of xero api.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Xero API Link](https://github.com/calcinai/xero-php) - Hope it helps. I have implemented Xero api by using this Git hub link. This library we can deploy and use in laravel framework or codeigniter framework. I used in laravel framework either you can use private or public type.

---

Configure Private Application settings first.

```
<?php
namespace XeroPHP\Application;
require '';


    use XeroPHP\Application;
    use XeroPHP\Models\Accounting\Invoice;

    class PrivateApplication extends Application
    {
        /**
         * @param array $config
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            $key = file_get_contents("file://privatekey.pem");
            $config = [
                'oauth' => [
                    'callback'         => 'http://localhost/',
                    'consumer_key'     => '',
                    'consumer_secret'  => '',
                    'rsa_private_key'  => $key,
                ],
            ];
            //As we don't need to Authorize/RequestToken, it's populated here.
            $config['oauth']['token'] = $config['oauth']['consumer_key'];

            parent::__construct($config);
        }
    }
```

---

And then create the Object for privateApplication and then use it.

```
public function get()
        {
            $xero = new PrivateApplication();

            $startDateString = date('Y, m, d');
            $endDateString = date('Y, m, d', strtotime('-30 days'));


             $invoices = $xero->load(Invoice::class)
                ->orderBy("Date", "DESC")
                ->where(sprintf('Date >= DateTime(%s)', $endDateString))
                ->where('Status', Invoice::INVOICE_STATUS_AUTHORISED)
                ->where('Type', Invoice::INVOICE_TYPE_ACCREC)

                ->execute();


           return $invoices;   
        }
```

Comment: Please add a code example here, as the link might become invalid in the future.

Comment: added some info about privateapplication

Comment: Please do not post code as screenshots. If anyone wants to reproduce it, he has to type it by his hands instead of c&p. Insert your code directly and format it as code.

Comment: Well, that looks much better!